# Constructing a new category from a monad

Tags: category-theory, monads

Given a monad $T: \mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$ with natural transformations $\eta: id \Rightarrow T$ and $\mu: T^2 \Rightarrow T$, I want to construct a new category $\mathbf{C}^T$ where objects are the same as $\mathbf{C}$ and the hom-sets are $Hom_{\mathbf{C}^T}(A,B)=Hom_{\mathbf{C}}(A,T(B))$ for objects $A, B$.

However, I'm not sure what composition in this category should look like. If I have  $Hom_{\mathbf{C}^T}(A,B) \ni f: A \to_T B$ where subscript $T$ denotes arrows in $\mathbf{C}^T$, then this is given by a morphism $f: A \to T(B)$ in $\mathbf{C}$. If I have $g:B \to_T C$ as a morphism $g:B\to T(C)$, I want to construct a composition $g \circ f :A \to_T C$ as a morphism $A \to T(C)$. But there seems to be no way to do this since there's no way to specify a morphism $T(B) \to B$ that we can use to compose with in $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Your constructed category is exactly just the Kleisli category of the monad $T$. Do you know how compositions are defined in Kleisli categories?

Comment: oh it has a name! I haven't heard of it no. I just saw this as an exercise in a category theory text

Comment: Side note: usually, $\mathbf{C}^T$ is the Eilenberg-Moore category of the monad and the Kleisli category is denoted by $\mathbf{C}_T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying $T$ to $g$ you get $T(g):T(B)\to T(T(C))$ which you can compose with $f$ to get $T(g)\circ f:A\to T(T(C))$.  Then you can compose with $\mu_C:T(T(C))\to T(C)$ to get a morphism to just $T(C)$.

(Incidentally, it is worthwhile to think about questions like this with some simple examples in mind.  For instance, if $T$ is the free monoid monad on sets, you're asking for a way to compose "maps" $A\to B$ which instead of giving an element of $B$ for each element of $A$ give a string of elements of $B$.  Given two such "maps" $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$, how would you define $g(f(a))$?  Well, $f(a)$ is a string of elements of $B$, so you can apply $g$ to each one of them to get a big string of elements of $C$.  If you unravel what this means in terms of the monad structure of $T$, you get the construction above.)